# How do i print the repetition output using regex it prints only first match

Tags: python, regex

I have task where I need to print the occurrence and count and non-occurrence and count

```
import re

sequence = '1222311'

m = re.search(r'(\d)\1+',sequence)

print(m)
```

**Exptected output :**

```
(1, 1) (3, 2) (1, 3) (2, 1)
```

In sequence need to check and print

```
 (cnt , val) -> 1222311 -> 1 as come only once -> (1,1) (cnt,number)
```

Comment: Does this similar post answer your question? [Counting sequential occurrences in a list and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57809568/counting-sequential-occurrences-in-a-list-and)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.finditer` to get start/end index of match and then construct your output ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sx8go5/2)):

```py
import re

sequence = '1222311'

out = [(m.end() - m.start(), int(m.group(1))) for m in re.finditer(r'(\d)\1*', sequence)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[(1, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1)]
```